# JavaScript: Search URL parameter and remove it including values

Tags: javascript

I've this URL here:

```
http://localhost.com/?size=L,M,S&color=Red,Blue,Green
```

The URL can also have this format:

```
http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green&size=L,M,S
```

I'm trying now to remove the parameter `color` completely including all parameters and the `&` in the first example or the `?` in the last one. If it's the last case I need to change the `&` from the `size` to `?`.

I've tried it this way but it just removes the prameter word without any params and all the other stuff:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search.replace('color', ''));
```

How can I do this what I've described above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use `URLSearchParams`, delete the `color`, then construct the search parameters again with `toString()`:

```js
function fixParams(search) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
  params.delete('color');
  const searchString = decodeURIComponent(params.toString());
  const newUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + (searchString ? '?' : '' ) + searchString;
  console.log(newUrl);
  // window.history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
}
fixParams('?color=Red,Blue,Green&size=L,M,S');
fixParams('?size=L,M,S&color=Red,Blue,Green');
fixParams('?color=Red,Blue,Green');
```

`URLSearchParams` will require a polyfill to work on very old browsers, though - so, another option would be to use a regular expression that matches `color=`, followed by non-`&` characters, followed by a `&` (if `color` is not the last parameter), *or* matches `[?&]color=`, followed by non-`&` characters, followed by the end of the string (if `color` is the last parameter) - then, replace the match with the empty string:

```js
function fixParams(name, search) {
  const re = new RegExp(name + '=[^&]*&|[?&]' + name + '=[^&]*$', 'g');
  // const newUrl = window.location.search.replace(re, '');
  const newUrl = search.replace(re, '');
  // window.history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
  console.log(newUrl);
}

fixParams('color', '?color=Red,Blue,Green&size=L,M,S');
fixParams('color', '?size=L,M,S&color=Red,Blue,Green');
fixParams('color', '?color=Red,Blue,Green');
```

```html
fixParams('foobar.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green&size=L,M,S');
fixParams('foobar.com/?size=L,M,S&color=Red,Blue,Green');
fixParams('foobar.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green');
```

Comment: The first one works great and I don't think that there are people which are using very old browsers today but what would you prefer? And there is a small problem with the first one because the , gets transformed into %2C. How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh, that's right, have to use `decodeURIComponent` as well. The main issue with `URLSearchParams` is that IE doesn't support it. I think `URLSearchParams` is the more *elegant* approach, but the regular expression is both shorter *and* more compatible, so I'd use the regex

Comment: Okay thank you so better use the last one. Is this right? Because I want to pass the value via a variable: var re = new RegExp(name + '[^&]*&|[?&]' + name + '[^&]*$/g');

Comment: When using the regex constructor, don't use the `/` delimiters, and to use flags, pass another parameter, eg `'g`, in addition to the first parameter (the string to construct the pattern from)

Comment: Looks like `name + '=[^&]*&|[?&]' + name + '=[^&]*$'` results in the proper pattern

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works now :) I've edited your answer to my working code.